# Can we write a Gaussian r.v. as $Y\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha U}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am facing the following problem.
Let $\alpha>0$ and $U \sim \mathcal U ([0,1])$.

Given a real valued random variable $Y$, independent of $U$ and admitting a density $f$ (wrt Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$), is it possible to choose $f$ such that the random variable $Z =Y\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha U}$ is gaussian?

Noting $w_f$ the density of $Z$, we have for every real $x$
$$
w_f(x) =\frac{1}{\alpha x}\int_x^{x\mathrm e^\alpha} f(y) \mathrm d y \text{ if } x \neq 0 \quad, \quad w_f(0)=\frac{ (\mathrm e^\alpha -1)}{\alpha} \text{ else}\;.
$$
Derivating the previous equation (possible in the gaussian case), we get the functional equation
$$
 (\mathrm e^\alpha f(\mathrm e^\alpha x) -f(x))=\alpha \left( xw_f'(x)+w_f(x)\right) \quad , \quad x\in\mathbb R\;.
$$

but I can't go further. Does anyone has a hint?

Comment: It might be easier to take characteristic functions (assuming independence), to work out what the characteristic function of $Y$ would have to be. Then you could invert it.

Comment: That's an idea, thanks!. I'm going to try this but with Mellin transform instead of Fourier. It seems more suited to study multiplicative r.v.'s.